# UICollectionReusableView for section header not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I created a UICollectionReusuable view for UICollecton view section header. I use the following code the implement the header view.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ThemeHeader *headerView = [[ThemeHeader alloc] init];
headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                 withReuseIdentifier:@"header"
                                                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *title = @"Title for the header";
headerView.title.text = title;
return headerView;
```

}

It crashes giving me the following error:

-[UICollectionReusableView title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac846a0'

My ThemeHeader class looks like this

```
@interface ThemeHeader : UICollectionReusableView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

@end
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating headerView and then reinitialising with dequequed View?

Comment: Is your title IBOutlet connected properly to its respective UILabel on nib?

Comment: Did you register class with a following method registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind: withReuseIdentifier: for your supplementary view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means `headerView` is not an instance of `ThemeHeader` as you expect but an instance of `UICollectionReusableView` which does not have a `title` property.

It could be because you might not have set `ThemeHeader` as custom class in the identity inspector on storyboard for this resuable view.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. Seems like a good answer to me.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you